# JSF databatable selected row

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

This may sound quite strange, but checking whether any possibilities are there to get datatable selected row value if action is not in datatable row.

I have the following in JSF page

```
    <p:dataTable id="det" var="emp" lazy="true"
value="#{myMB.lazyModel}" paginator="true"
paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10"
    rowKey="#{emp.employeeNumber}">

    <f:facet name="header">                  
        Employee Details    
    </f:facet>
```

If I add the following inside `<p:column> </p:column>` I am able to get the `selectedDepartment` row in ManagedBean, but if I add button  above  `<p:column> </p:column>`, i.e. not in datatable row, but on the heading, I am not able to get the `selectedDepartment` row because it is not in datatable row.

Are there any way I can get the selectedDepartment row if I add a button not in datatable row?

```
             <p:commandButton id="addEmployee" 
              icon="ui-icon-plus"                          
              oncomplete="newEmployeeDialog.show()" >
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{emp}" 
     target="#{myMB.selectedDepartment}" />   
      </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: You can use `<p:commandButton action="setDepartment(det)" />` and avoid using `<f:setPropertyActionListener />`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So action calling `setDepartment` method which accepts parameter or passing id of datatable det to set method?

Comment: I guess it would be better the first one.

Comment: @Polppan, You must select the row somehow, for example add checkbox/radio column , and when clicking on that row checkbox/radio you will be able to set the right `#{emp}`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the info like rowId if you dont put button inside the row. I suggest you first get an id from dataTable then take it into any hidden value to use it in commandButton.